# Errors in xampp/lampp

Tags: mysql, lamp, xampp

So, I got everything running and such but in the xampp gui nothing would work when I attempted to launch MySql.

I decided to open in terminal to get the error. Turns out I keep getting

`/opt/lampp/bin/mysqld_safe_helper: Can't create/write to file '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mylaptop.err' (errcode 13 "permission denied")`

I've looked over existing threads, and none seem to work? Help!

Comment: How did you install xampp/lampp? Which user did you use?

Comment: Can you provide the output for executing  `ls -l /opt/lampp/` and `ls -l /opt/lampp/var/mysql/`?

Answer (score 0):

This is some ownership issue. Depending on with which user you have installed xampp/lampp, you should try starting it with the same user.

You can check your permissions with `ls -l /opt/lampp/` and `ls -l /opt/lampp/var/mysql/`.

Furthermore, you can change the ownership of specific files so that this issue gets resolved, which I would not recommend because when xampp/lampp gets installed properly there is no need for changing permissions of specific files.

Alternatively, you can run it as root, where no error should persist.

I commonly install and start it with a sudo user.

Read the XAMPP documentation to find out what is recommended.

Additionally, in case you haven't done so, I recommend you starting xampp/lampp from terminal by executing `cd /opt/lampp && ./lampp start` for the purpose of debugging. This will also show you the state of the MySql server after it was trying to start it. So it will show you whether the MySql server could be started properly.

Comment: I own both dir.

Comment: edit: I just gave up and re installed ubuntu, and i face new errors after getting lamp to run. (apache and mysql run fine)